# how to pass hidden field value or html column value to another jsp page with in liferay portlet?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have one html table in my custom portlet of liferay.
i want to give edit functionality on click of that particular collumn 
i know that liferay-ui:search-container provides functionality like this but am using my html table and some jquery for this..so on hover of that particular collumn i have one edit icon and i want that on click of that edit icon i will redirect to edit page.but what i jus want is that how can i get primary key of that row's edit icon is selected..??

i have following jquery for icon displays and redirect to edit page

```
 <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {     
                        $(".editable").hover(function(){
                            $(this).append("<i class='splashy-pencil_right'></i>")
                        }, function(){
                            $(this).children("i").remove();
                        });                        
                        $(".editable").click(function(){
                            $.colorbox({
                                initialHeight: '0',
                                initialWidth: '0',
                                href: "#confirm_dialog",
                                inline: true,
                                opacity: '0.3',
                                onComplete: function(){
                                    $('.confirm_yes').click(function(e){
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        window.location.href = "<%=editURL.toString() %> ";
                                        $.colorbox.close();
                                    });
                                    $('.confirm_no').click(function(e){
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        $.colorbox.close(); 
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        //* show all elements & remove preloader                        
                        setTimeout('$("html").removeClass("js")',1000);
                    });
                </script>
```

following is my portletaction url on which i want to redirect

```
<portlet:actionURL name="editRestaurant" var="editURL">
       <portlet:param name="key" value="<%=restId%>" />
       </portlet:actionURL>
```

and following code is of my field of view classes in which am taking primary key value(restID) as a hidden field.

```
      <form action="<%=editURL.toString() %>" method="post">                       
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dt_gal_res">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="table_checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="select_rows" class="select_rows" data-tableid="dt_gal_rest" /></th>                                        
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                        <th>Contact Person</th>
                                        <th>Website</th>
                                        <th>Emenu</th>                                        
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>





        <% 
     List<restaurant> rest_listOBJ= restaurantLocalServiceUtil.getAllAvailableRestaurant();

for(int i=0;i<(rest_listOBJ.size());i++)
{

restaurant temprest=rest_listOBJ.get(i);

%>
     <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" name="row_sel" class="row_sel" /></td>                                        
                                            <td style="visibility: hidden;"><input type="text" name="primerykey" value="<%= temprest.getPrimaryKey()%>"></td>
                                            <td class="editable"><%=temprest.getName() %></td>
                                            <td><%=temprest.getContactno() %></td>
                                            <td><%=temprest.getWebsite() %></td>
                                            <td><%=temprest.getNoofemenuagent() %></td>
                                            <td><a href="#" class="pop_over" data-content="Ad Displayed on </br> <b>Restaurant</b> : ABC" data-original-title="( Ad name )" data-placement="left">Pending</a></td>                                        
                                        </tr>                                    
                                   </tbody>
```

so how can i transfer this clicked row or collumn value to the edit_restaurant.jsp page?

Answer (score 2):

Create a link and add the id as a parameter

```
<% PortletURL link = RenderResponse.createRenderURL();
link.setParameter("paramName", "paramValue");  
link.setParameter("jspPage", "/page.jsp"); %>
```

Use the link:
`<a href="<%= link.toString() %>">LinkText</a>`

On the jsp you can use this parameter the mvc way using:

`ParamUtil.getString(ActionRequest, "paramName");`

Comment: thanks ..i had solved my question with some javascript code which calling on button click ,,and getting id of that button in hidden field and then getting that value on redirected pagewith request.getattribute...your question helped me somewhat